# $X$ is a connected compact metric space. Is every $C^*$-embedding $M_n(\mathbb C)\to M_n(C(X))$ unitarily equivalent to the trivial one?

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory

$M_n=M_n(\mathbb C)$ is the $n\times n$ complex matrix algebra and $M_n(C(X))$ is the algebra of continuous functions from $X$ to $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

There is a trivial homomorphism $M_n\to M_n(C(X))$ which maps a matrix to a constant function taking value in $M_n$. Is every nonzero homomorphism unitarily equivalent to the trivial one?

---

Denote by $e_i$ the $n$ orthogonal equivalent projections in $M_n$. if $\varphi:M_n\to M_n(C(X))$ is a nonzero homomorphism, $\varphi(e_i)=p_i$ are equivalent projections such that $p_1+\cdots +p_n=1_n\otimes 1_X$. Assume $p_i$ are not stably equivalent to the trivial projections $e_i\otimes 1_X$ (though stably equivalent projections are not necessarily equivalent), then $[p_i]\neq [e_i\otimes 1_X]$. Since $n[p_i]=n[e_i\otimes 1_X]$, it follows that $K_0(C(X))$ can not be torsion-free.

Take this as an example. Let $X$ be the CW complex obtained by attaching the 2-dimensional disc $D^2=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\leq 1\}$ to the circle $S^1=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|=1\}$ via a degree 2 map. It is known that $K_0(C(X))\simeq \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z$, which can be computed using

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K_0(S^2\mathbb C)\simeq \mathbb Z @>>> K_0(C(X)) @>>> \mathbb Z\simeq K_0(C(S^1))\\
@AAA @. @VVV \\
K_1(C(S^1))\simeq \mathbb Z @<<< K_1(C(X)) @<<< 0=K_1(S^2\mathbb C)
\end{CD}$$

and

$$\begin{CD}
K_0(S^2\mathbb C) @>>> K_0(C(S^2))\\
@VVV  @VVV \\
K_0(C(X)) @>>> K_0(C(X)\oplus \mathbb C).
\end{CD}$$

One computes that the generator in $K_0(S^2\mathbb C)$ is represented by $\left[\left(\begin{array}{}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)\right]-\left[\left(\begin{array}{}1-zz^*&-z(1-z^*z)^{1/2}\\-z^*(1-z^*z)^{1/2}&z^*z\end{array}\right)\right]\in K_0(C(S^2))$.

Hence $\left[\left(\begin{array}{}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)\right]=(0,1)$ and $\left[\left(\begin{array}{}1-zz^*&-z(1-z^*z)^{1/2}\\-z^*(1-z^*z)^{1/2}&z^*z\end{array}\right)\right]=(1,1)$ in $K_0(C(X))\simeq \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z$. It then follows $\left[\left(\begin{array}{}1-zz^*&-z(1-z^*z)^{1/2}\\-z^*(1-z^*z)^{1/2}&z^*z\end{array}\right)\right]=\left[\left(\begin{array}{}zz^*&z(1-z^*z)^{1/2}\\z^*(1-z^*z)^{1/2}&1-z^*z\end{array}\right)\right]$.

I don't think they are unitarily equivalent but I have no proof.

Comment: Sorry but what is $M_n$ and what is $C(X)$?

Comment: $M_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix space and $C(X)$ is the continous function space.

Comment: $M_n(C(X))$ is the space of continous functions on $X$ taking values in $M_n$.

Comment: You should add all necessary definitions to your question: $M_n, C(X)$, which field is used, $K_0$ (the tags suggest that it is the $0$-th algebraic $K$-group). This is a service to the readers: You expect that people spend their time to answer your question, so people deserve to get all information without reading comments.

Comment: @PaulFrost: for a question tagged "C$^*$-algebras", what you ask is similar to requiring someone asking a calculus question to define the symbols $\displaystyle\int$ and $dx$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I tend to agree and I was in the process of writing a comment with the same intent, but after reconsidering I think Paul Frost has a point here. Someone with a background in algebraic topology may arrive here through the (toplogical) K-theory tag, feel suitably prepared to answer questions on this topic and then be irritated by the unknown notation. For them the single tag C*-algebras might slip through, and a clearer reference to operator algebras in the question body might be warranted.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I was asking, because I have read about (topological) Ktheory, but have no background in C*-algebras. The difference between $\int$ and $M_n$ is that the former is fairly unambiguous (from context it is clear that we don’t speak about (co)ends in category theory), while $M_n$ can denote matrices, manifolds, gradings of a module and many more things… So I would agree with Paul Frost that it would have been nice to have the definitions.